# Php put content: Data erased

Tags: php

I have this simple web content editor.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {
        if (file_put_contents('homecontent.txt', $_POST['homecontent']) !== FALSE)
            echo '<p class="success">Home Content Saved Successfully!</p>', "\n";
    }
    $homecontent = file_get_contents('homecontent.txt');

    if (isset($_POST['header'])) {
        if (file_put_contents('headercontent.txt', $_POST['headercontent']) !== FALSE)
            echo '<p class="success">Header Content Saved Successfully!</p>', "\n";
    }
    $headercontent = file_get_contents('headercontent.txt');

  if (isset($_POST['cssfile'])) {
        if (file_put_contents('style.css', $_POST['cssfile']) !== FALSE)
            echo '<p class="success>Style.css Saved Successfully!</p>', "\n";
    }
    $cssfile = file_get_contents('style.css');
?>

<div id="forms">

<form method="post" action="">
    <p>Here you can edit your homepage text:</p>
    <textarea name="homecontent" id="homecontent" rows="20"><?php echo $homecontent?></textarea>
    <p><buton type="submit" name="edit">Save changes</button></p>
</form>   


<form method="post" action="">
    <p>Here you can edit your header content:</p>
    <textarea name="headercontent" id="headercontent" rows="10"><?php echo $headercontent?></textarea>
    <p><button type="submit" name="header">Save changes</button></p>
</form>    </div>

<form method="post" action="">
    <p>Here you can edit style.css file:</p>
    <textarea name="cssfile" id="cssfile" rows="10"><?php echo $css?></textarea>
    <p><button type="submit" name="cssfile">Save changes</button></p>
</form>
```

The problem in this script is that 3rd form action is not getting executed. I get success message, but style.css file not written & it also erases any existing content. The first 2 form actions are working perfectly fine.

It cannot be a directory permission error because other 2 file are working.

Comment: what is some example content in $_POST['cssfile'] ?  as a test, try file_put_contents('style.css', 'hello world') !== FALSE  ... if that works, you know the issue is related to the content of $_POST['cssfile']

Comment: wrong variable. Error reporting would have told you that. Plus, a typo `<buton type="submit"`

Comment: I saw the typo too, but supposed it would be okay in the original source, because otherwise there would be no submit button which would strike right away.

Comment: "buton" and "button" @syck are two different animals altogether, that's **IF** that's what the OP's *really* using here. If they're using "buton", I highly doubt that works.

Comment: Thats what I was trying to say. =)

Comment: There is no button typo error & wrong file echo  in the original script. It came here because I edited the script lots of time. The </div> wasn't a mistake, because the 3rd form was sitting on a separate <div> for advanced options.

Comment: @devlincarnate : Thanks, your suggestion is working! But the content disappears after I submit the form :( Error log is not recording anything as I'm getting success message.

Answer (score 2):

Your submit button is named same as the textarea, so it overwrites it. Change the form to

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <p>Here you can edit style.css file:</p>
    <textarea name="cssfile" id="cssfilecontent" rows="10"><?php echo $cssfile; ?></textarea>
    <p><button type="submit" name="cssfile">Save changes</button></p>
</form>
```

Up in the PHP section, you will have to change

```
if (isset($_POST['cssfile'])) {
        if (file_put_contents('style.css', $_POST['cssfilecontent']) !== FALSE)
            echo '<p class="success>Style.css Saved Successfully!</p>', "\n";
    }
    $cssfile = file_get_contents('style.css');
```

And, of course, `<p><buton type="submit"` in the first form misses a `t`. The `</div>` which is after the second form should be after the third, I suppose.

Comment: also `$cssfile = file_get_contents('style.css');` and echo-ing `$css`

Comment: Why even naming a submit button?

Comment: @AlexTartan I silently changed that as well.

Comment: you missed something; see comments ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I missed even uncommented things. But thats a thing about the speed of typing.

Comment: and now, to see what the OP has to say ;-) you know how newbies can be at times.

Comment: Seems like it, or doesn't know how to close a question when a solution is given.

Comment: @Fred-ii- But did you notice that he commented only the question but not the answer? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestion. I finally got it working

```
if (isset($_POST['cssfile']))
        {

            if (file_put_contents('style.txt', $_POST['csscontent']) !== FALSE)            echo '<p class="success">Style.css Saved Successfully!</p>', "\n";
        }

       $csscontent = file_get_contents('style.txt');


      ?>

  <html><body>

  <form method="post" action="">
      <p>Here you can edit style.css file:</p>
      <textarea name="csscontent" id="csscontent" rows="10"><?php  echo $csscontent ?></textarea>
      <p><button type="submit" name="cssfile">Save changes</button></p>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

The textarea name & id should be the same. The same name should be entered on put_content $_POST